# SQL - How to Count from multiple tables and add them together

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, count

I am trying to do a count from multiple tables but there could be multiple entries in each table. Here is simple sample data simplified. There are actually more then 3 tables but just so I get an understanding of how to do it

```
table2      table2          table3
person_ID   person_id       person_id
1                  1        2
2                  1        2
3                  2        1
4                  2        4
5                  4        5
```

I'm trying to get a count of each person ID in each table so the output would be the following. Note that personID is a key I don't need the addition of the number of the ID not 2+2+2+2. But the count of the number of appearances it makes in the all tables then the count in each table added together for total number of appearances it makes. Basically I'm trying to find a total number of items attached to each personID

```
person_id    total
1             4
2             4
3             1
4             3    
5             2
```

Answer (score 3):

Select the ids from all the tables together with`union`. That result can be grouped by the id and counted for each

```
select person_id, count(*) as count
from
(
    select person_id from table1
    union all
    select person_id from table2
    union all
    select person_id from table3 
) tmp
group by person_id
```